# maximum recursion depth is exceeded error while calling a Python object in django while making a post request in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to list all the doubtclasses model using doubtclass view but there is some recursion error in the post request, which i am not able to understand , i search  across for same error and i have tried if i made a similar mistake to the other developers that have asked the same question but as far as i searched mine one is different

**My doubtclass view**

```
class DoubtClass(LoginRequiredMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.DoubtClass_serializer
    queryset = models.DoubtClasses.objects.filter(is_draft=False)
    def get(self, request):
        print("error in doubtclass get")
        return self.list(request)
    def post(self, request):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return self.post(request)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

**my doubtclass model**

```
class DoubtClasses(models.Model):
    doubtClass_details = models.TextField()
    class_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    doubtsAddressed = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    no_of_students_registered = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    no_of_students_attended = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    mentor_id = models.ForeignKey(Mentor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    is_draft = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'DoubtClasses'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.doubtClass_details
```

I am new to  django

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For better help formatting questions, I definitely recommend reading how to create a [mre]. In this case, we really need access to the exact error message and any relevant lines of code that go along with it to answer this question.

Comment: Well in your `post` method you just keep recursively calling itself in case the user is a superuser. Did you want to call the _super_ `post` method there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code it seems you want to limit `post` requests to superusers. The problem with your implementation is that you are just calling `post` *again* recursively. Seeing as you inherit from `CreateModelMixin` you likely want to call `create` instead:

```
class DoubtClass(LoginRequiredMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.DoubtClass_serializer
    queryset = models.DoubtClasses.objects.filter(is_draft=False)
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("error in doubtclass get")
        return self.list(request)
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs) # call `create` instead
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

But this can be improved. Firstly instead of inheriting from `ListModelMixin`, `CreateModelMixin` and `GenericAPIView` you can simply reduce that to inheriting from `generics.ListCreateAPIView`. Next instead of using `LoginRequiredMixin` it is better to use the `IsAuthenticated` permission. Also for your limitation of POST requests being limited to superusers that can also be added to a custom permission:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission, IsAuthenticated, SAFE_METHODS


class IsSuperuserOrReadOnly(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return bool(
            request.method in SAFE_METHODS or
            request.user and
            request.user.is_superuser
        )


class DoubtClass(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.DoubtClass_serializer
    queryset = models.DoubtClasses.objects.filter(is_draft=False)
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsSuperuserOrReadOnly]
```